# BufReadPre and reading viminfo file

Tags: viminfo

I need to backup the registers and settings of a limited group of files.  I'm more interested in what can be saved in a viminfo file, less interested in sessionss.

I'm having a problem reading **viminfo** file upon `BufReadPre`.

```
au BufReadPre,FileReadPre  *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ '/path/to/file/\d\{3}-' | 
:verbose rv c:/Users/path/to/viminfo.vim
```

If I open a file that matches the above regex, everything's ok: the **viminfo** file is read.

However, if I open subsequent files (that also match the above regex) using eg. `:e myfile.md`, there is no indication that the **viminfo** file is read (using `:mess`).

This is driving me nuts!! Can you help please?

BTW: I'm logging **events** and can see quite clearly that `BufReadPre` is being triggered on the occasions mentioned above.

```
" ftplugin/markdown.vim

function! Dev_autocommands_enter()
            :let g:style="design"
            :set fenc=utf8
            :set lines=34
            :set cursorline
            :set wildmenu
            :set wildmode=full
            :verbose rv c:/Users/path/to/_dev/testing/vim/macros/viminfo-registers.vim
            :map <C-j> :bprev<CR>
            :map <C-k> :bnext<CR>
            :nmap <A-o> o<ESC>k
            :nmap <A-O> O<ESC>j
endfunc

if !exists("mdCmds_loaded")
    augroup mdCmds
        autocmd!
        au BufReadPre,FileReadPre  *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ '/path/_dev/testing/\d\{3}-' | 
            :call Dev_autocommands_enter()
        au BufUnload *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ '/path/_dev/testing/\d\{3}-' | 
            \ :verbose wv c:/Users/path/to/_dev/testing/vim/macros/viminfo-registers.vim
    augroup end
    let mdCmds_loaded = 1
endif
```

Comment: If the code posted isn't the actual code, then perhaps you could share a closer example? The code talks about a viminfo file, but later you say function. Also, assuming ftplugins/the `FileType` event isn't good enough for this, you could try using `BufRead` and `BufNewFile`—those are what is typically used for filetype-detection.

Comment: Also looks like you're missing `endif` and a continuation marker `\\`

Comment: Actually, I suspect that's the issue: the `rv` command could be run at vimrc time instead of installed as the autocommand. Can you check `:autocmd {your-group}`?

Comment: No need to add "edit" markers. The goal is for the question to read fluidly and clearly. OTOH, I'm not sure the image adds anything. Have you considered using sessions?

Comment: I would start with simplifying the whole thing. First thing fixing is adding the `:endif` commands. I actually wonder, why you did not get an error message

Comment: Is that all in `ftplugin/markdown.vim`? `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` runs whenever the filetype is set to markdown (though I prefer `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, because I usually want to allow the `$VIMRUNTIME` scripts to run first). What I mean to say is that those autocommands won't be installed at the right time, if they are set in an ftplugin

Comment: Surely the `ftplugin/markdown.vim` file runs whenever vim opens a file of type `markdown'? How won't these autocommands be installed at the right time?

Comment: I realise now that `ftplugin/files` are sourced **after** all of the `BufRead` events. Makes my issue weird. I think it may have been my omission, as mentioned above, of leaving off the `endif`.